# Is GetX state management faster than Bloc? - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-getx

I have a quick question about state management in Flutter. I am into GetX for a while especially when it comes to state management, but it makes me wonder what's actually faster - GetX state management or Bloc? I am talking only about state management and no other additional possibilities that comes with GetX.
Is the difference in the speed between those two packages even that big enough that should matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the performance of state management doesn't matter that much, it's a small fraction of the time spent in Flutter's render pipeline.

The [DevTools performance view](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/devtools/performance) is an excellent way of illustrating this.

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends upon how you write and structure your code. GetX just removes the Boilerplate code for you and makes life easier. To make your app faster, avoid using *Functional* widgets inside ListView/ScrollView.
Here's a video which might help you improve the performance of your app: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vVg9It7cOfY